Transforming Hessian to original parameters after centering and QR-transforming X
I'm starting to more routinely mean-center and QR-rotate design matrices $X$ when doing maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) or Bayesian posterior sampling.  This helps with convergence and quickens posterior sampling when there are collinearities.  After mean-centering columns of $X$, the R qr function transforms (orthonormalizes) $X$, and provides a matrix Rinv (which I'll abbreviate as $R$) that can be multiplied by the parameter vector to obtain parameters on the original scale.  Then the mean-centering is reversed to adjust the intercept(s).  I'm using a proportional odds semiparametric model for $k+1$ distinct value of the dependent variable $Y$, so there are $k$ intercepts $\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{k}$.  On the original scale when there are $p$ columns of $X$, there are $p$ regression coefficients $\beta_{1}, \ldots, \beta_{p}$.  Suppose that MLEs on transformed $X$ are $\delta$ and $\gamma$ corresponding to the $\alpha, \beta$ on the original $X$.
It is easy to compute $\alpha, \beta$ from $\delta, \gamma$ given the matrix $R$ and the vector of means.  Let $M$ be the $k$-row row-duplicated matrix with $p$ columns containing the $p$ original column means of $X$, i.e. $M = 1_{k\times 1} \times \bar{X}$ where $\bar{X}$ is a $1\times p$ vector of means.  Then pre-processing of $X$ is $(X - \bar{X})R$ where $R$ is from running QR on $X - \bar{X}$, and
$\beta = R \gamma$
$\alpha = \delta - M R \gamma$
Let $H$ denote the $(k+p)\times (k+p)$ matrix of second partial derivatives of the log-likelihood function for $\delta, \gamma$.  Partition $H$ as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{k\times k} & B_{k \times p} \newline
B' & D_{p\times p}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
My understanding is that $H$ on a transformed-parameter scale is computed by
$J'HJ$
where the Jacobian $J$ is given by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial\delta} & \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial\gamma} \newline
\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\delta}  & \frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\gamma}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which equals
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{k\times k} & -M_{k\times p}R_{p\times p} \newline
0_{p\times k} & R_{p\times p}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $I$ is an identity matrix and $0$ a matrix of zeros.
My R code for computing the transformed $H$ is
M <- matrix(1, nrow=k, ncol=1) %*% matrix(xbar, nrow=1)
J <- rbind(cbind(diag(k),                   -M %*% R),
           cbind(matrix(0, nrow=p, ncol=k), R       )  )
H2 <- t(J) %*% H %*% J

But in my examples, the value I'm getting for H2, especially the lower right submatrix for $\beta$, is way off.  Can someone spot where I've gone wrong?  In the Bayesian setting everything is easy since you just compute $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for each posterior draw and you get the correct posterior distributions for the original parameters.
There are two things I know:

I get exact agreement for $\alpha, \beta$ using the above formulas, when comparing to coefficients estimating from running on the original raw $X$.
The formulas above fail to get the right transformed Hessian even when $k=p=1$, i.e., the model is a binary logistic regression with a single predictor.  (The correct reference Hessian comes from -solve(vcov(fit)) where fit was computed on the raw $X$, i.e., the correct Hessian is the negative of the inverse of the variance-covariance matrix for $\alpha, \beta$.).
When $R$ is set to an identity matrix and $\bar{X}$ to zero, the correct Hessian results, i.e., the adjusted Hessian equals the original Hessian.


It looks like you are asking how to compute the matrix of mixed partial derivatives $$\frac{\partial^2f(y)}{\partial y_i\partial y_j}$$ in terms of $x$ where $y = \phi(x)$ is a (linear) transformation of $\mathbb R^{k+p}$ (and $f$ is a log likelihood).  Would that be correct?

Maybe slightly more aligned with the original question is how to compute the matrix of second partial derivatives with respect to transformed variables $y$ when the original Hessian matrix involved derivatives with respect to $x$.  And there are the particular transformations, which are partitioned in to intercepts and slopes.  Then there's possible programming errors ...

I wish that worked, but alas no.

Just to make sure I understand: you're talking about two applications of the Chain Rule, right?  (I wouldn't want to offer that as an answer without first making sure it's the intended interpretation.)

Yes it’s a standard vector calculus result where you use a Jacobian (consisting of all the first derivatives in both directions) to transform a Hession (of all 2nd partial derivatives) in a change-of-variables problem.  The Jacobian approach is derived from 2 applications of the chain rule, putting everything together nicely with matrices.  It’s probably a case where I’ve transposed something or computing derivatives in a wrong direction.

I added some bullet points at the end of the original post to list some known facts about the setup.

Wondering whether the madness package might be helpful here?

any chance you could get us a simulated example showing us the problem?

TL;DR
The correct Hessian matrix on the original scale, i.e. in the $(\alpha, \beta)$-parameterization, is given by
$$
J^{-\top} H J^{-1} = (J H^{-1} J^\top)^{-1},
$$
with
$$
J^{-1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{k\times k} & M_{k\times p} \\
0_{p\times k} & R^{-1}_{p\times p}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Background
For a fixed outcome $x$, let $\ell_x^{\alpha, \beta} : \mathbb R^{k+p} \to \mathbb R$ denote the log-likelihood function of $(\alpha, \beta).$ Define the linear transformation $T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}: \mathbb R^{k+p} \to \mathbb R^{k+p}$ by $T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}(\tilde\alpha,\tilde\beta) = (\tilde\delta, \tilde\gamma) \mathrel{:=}(\tilde\alpha + M\tilde\beta, R^{-1}\tilde\beta)$, and $T_{\delta, \gamma}^{\alpha, \beta}: \mathbb R^{k+p} \to \mathbb R^{k+p}$ as the inverse of $T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}$, i.e., $T_{\delta, \gamma}^{\alpha, \beta}(\tilde\delta, \tilde\gamma) =  (\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta) \mathrel{:=} (\tilde\delta - MR\tilde\gamma, R\tilde\gamma).$
We are interested in the Hessian matrix of $\ell_x^{\alpha, \beta}$ at $(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta), H_{\ell_x^{\alpha, \beta}}(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta)$.
Since $\ell_x^{\alpha, \beta} = \ell_x^{\delta, \gamma} \circ T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}$, where $\ell_x^{\delta, \gamma} \mathrel{:=} \ell_x^{\alpha, \beta} \circ T_{\delta, \gamma}^{\alpha, \beta}$ is the log-likelihood function of $(\delta, \gamma)$, the chain rule yields
$$
H_{\ell_x^{\alpha, \beta}}(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta) = J_{T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}}(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta)^\top H_{\ell_x^{\delta, \gamma}}(\tilde\delta, \tilde\gamma) J_{T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}}(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta),
$$
with $J_{T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}}(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta)$ the Jacobian matrix of $T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}$ at $(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta)$.
By the inverse function theorem, we have $J_{T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}}(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta) = J_{T_{\delta, \gamma}^{\alpha, \beta}}^{-1}(\tilde\delta, \tilde\gamma)$ and thus
$$
H_{\ell_x^{\alpha, \beta}}(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta) = J_{T_{\delta, \gamma}^{\alpha, \beta}}^{-1}(\tilde\delta, \tilde\gamma)^\top H_{\ell_x^{\delta, \gamma}}(\tilde\delta, \tilde\gamma) J_{T_{\delta, \gamma}^{\alpha, \beta}}^{-1}(\tilde\delta, \tilde\gamma).
$$

Addendum
If $T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}$ were a general (possibly nonlinear) transformation, the chain rule (or Faà di Bruno's formula) would yield
$$
H_{\ell_x^{\alpha, \beta}}(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta) = J_{T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}}(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta)^\top H_{\ell_x^{\delta, \gamma}}(\tilde\delta, \tilde\gamma) J_{T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}}(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta) + \sum_{i=1}^{k+p} \partial_i \ell_x^{\delta, \gamma}(\tilde\delta, \tilde\gamma)H_{\pi_i \circ T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}}(\tilde\alpha, \tilde\beta),
$$
where $\pi_i: \mathbb R^{k+p} \to \mathbb R$ denotes the projection onto the $i$-th coordinate and $(\tilde\delta, \tilde\gamma) = T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}(\tilde\alpha,\tilde\beta)$ is redefined according to the new transformation $T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}$.
When $T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}$ is linear, the Hessian matrix of each $\pi_i \circ T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}$ in the second term (and thus the term itself) vanishes and the Jacobian matrix of $T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}$ coincides with the transformation matrix of $T_{\alpha, \beta}^{\delta, \gamma}$.

I don't think so.  For the case $k=p=1$ we start with a model $\alpha+\beta X$ and fit the model on transformed $X$ as $\delta + \gamma r (X-\bar{X}) = \delta - \gamma r \bar{X} + \gamma r X$ where $r$ is a scalar from the QR algorithm.  Lining up terms we get $\alpha = \delta - r\bar{X}\gamma$.

That did it!  I'll mark this as the answer.  Would you mind doing one thing first?  I went "by the book" in taking the right partial derivatives to form the Jacobian, then using $J'HJ$.  Would you please expand on the formalism of setting up the problem? The linear map you wrote makes sense but I thought it was more obvious to speak of $(\delta, \gamma) \rightarrow (\alpha, \beta)$ directly, which I thought led to a $J$ that did not need inversion.  I also tested ChatGPT on this point and it came up with the wrong direction just as I did.  Write a non-inversion-needed $J$ from the outset?

@FrankHarrell I hope my edited answer elaborates on this in sufficient detail.

Exceptionally well!  Thank so much for solving a problem that I spent an inordinate amount of time on.

@FrankHarrell Perfect, I'm glad I could help. I've added a possibly useful extension to nonlinear transformations as well.

I've written this up with more context here.  If you want to provide your name I'd be delighted to attribute this to you in a better way.
